# How can I test the difference between VGA and DVI output on my display card

Tags: graphics-card, display

I have an [Nvidia 9400 GT](http://www.geforce.com/hardware/desktop-gpus/geforce-9400-gt) which has both a DVI and VGA outputs. Besides the signal loss through the analog VGA cable (which I can't see), can I expect to see a difference in performance if I change to the DVI output, and how could I test this?

PS. Same monitor has both DVI (digital) and VGA inputs

Comment: Over a short distance (i.e. Your desktop on the floor to your monitor above), you shouldn't really notice anything.  Refresh would still be the same (as determined by the monitor), resolution, colors, etc.  Really the degradation happens over length & # of connections (I think VGAs distance is like 26ft, and don't couple a few VGA cables together).  Otherwise, probably nothing noticeable what-so-ever.

Comment: As nerdwaller said, as long as you avoid other cables (esp. power cables) you should notice no difference.